# Object doesn't get saved immediately in Spring Boot @PostMapping()

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, rest, backend

So I am currently working on a Spring Boot backend application, and what I've noticed is that when I try to return the saved object in a POST request, the elements that are connected to the current element with a @OneToMany relationship don't update while I'm in that method.

The entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="APPOINTMENT")
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    private Teacher teacher;

    @Column
    private Date date;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Request> requestList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String neptunCode;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

The AppointmentController: (I will create a service layer later)

```
@PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Appointment> post(@RequestBody Appointment appointment) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(appointmentRepository.save(appointment));
    }
```

Even when I try something like this, I still get null for the name etc.:

```
@PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Appointment> post(@RequestBody Appointment appointment) {
        appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(appointmentRepository.findById(2).get());
    }
```

(I currently have 1 item INSERTED into the in-memory database when it runs, so ID number 2 returns this newly added item)

This is what I send in the POST request body:

```
{
    "student": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "teacher": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "date": "2050-05-05"
}
```

And this is what I get back:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "student": {
        "id": 1,
        "neptunCode": null,
        "email": null,
        "name": null
    },
    "teacher": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null,
        "neptunCode": null,
        "department": null,
        "email": null,
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "maxStudents": 0
    },
    "date": "2050-05-05"
}
```

When I do another POST after this, the previous request "gets registered", and it also shows correctly when I do a GET request for this element right after this POST.

What is even weirder, is that when I do a PUT request and update an entity, it works correctly, and I get back the updatet element:

```
@PutMapping("/{appointmentId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Appointment> put(@RequestBody Appointment appointment, @PathVariable Integer appointmentId) {
        Optional<Appointment> oAppointment = appointmentRepository.findById(appointmentId);
        if (oAppointment.isPresent()) {
            appointment.setId(appointmentId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(appointmentRepository.save(appointment));
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
```

**I have been Googling the solution for this, and have found some people suggesting to use saveAndFlush() method, but that also does nothing.**

Is there a way this can be fixed somehow or just tell me why this is happening?

PS.: I don't want to actually return the whole object after a POST, but this issue is now bugging me and I have to know why this is happening... :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which repository type do you extend in your repository interface?

Comment: @IsaToltar I am currently using CrudRepository but I also tried it with JpaRespository. Neither work.

Comment: Update: I've noticed that calling the setId() method invokes cascading for some reason. (but I can't do that because I need auto generated IDs)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inserting a new data to table directly from controller is a bad idea. You need implement a service class to work with repository. You will do @Autowire or any other injection of repository and from this service class will insert data.
Do not send new entity class from post request, instead of it, create new VM class, and map from VM class to new entity. You should create an instance of new entity, this will give you valid ID for your table.

Example:

1. AppointmentVM.java

```
    public class AppointmentVM {
        private Long studentId;
        private Long teacherId;
        private Date date;
    }
```

2. Controller

```
@PostMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<Appointment> post(@RequestBody AppointmentVM appointmentVm) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(appointmentService.save(appointmentVm));
}
```

3. AppointmentService

```
public Appointment save(AppointmentVM appointmentVm) {
    Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
    appointment.setStudentId(appointmentVm.getStudentId());
    appointment.setTeacherId(appointmentVm.getTeacherId());
    appointment.setDate(appointmentVm.getDate());
    return appointmentRepository.save(appointment);
}
```

In that way instance of new appointment entity will get generated ID and must be saved successfully.